# The main difference between internal js file and external js file

Tags: javascript

Is there any different between include external js file and write down javascript in the html page.

Case 1

test.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
alert('aaa');
```

Case 2

test.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            alert('aaa');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Case 1 execute more faster than Case2 if my memory services me right. But I am not sure. Moreover, I cannot find the relative documents or articles to support my ideal. May someone help me?

Comment: http://webdesign.about.com/od/speed/a/script-placement-for-speed.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 1 is is slightly slower at first, because it needs to do a second request to get the script, so there is a little overhead.

However, the browser will cache the javascript file, so if you have multiple pages that share the same script, Case 2 will be more efficient, because for subsequent pages, the browser already has the cached script and doesn't need to download it again.

Also, most browsers will allow opening two connections to the same server, so it may download the page and the script simultaneously on the first request, although it depends on size of the page and the script, the server, the client and the internet properties (latency and speed) which solution is faster.

Comment: One source of information are the various SEO tools that tell you to move inline scripts to separate files, but you can also read [this article](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/inline-vs-separate-file) or [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/86589/why-should-i-avoid-inline-scripting). I googled for *"better inline script or separate file"* and got pages full of references of which those articles are a random two.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: will retreive the script from the server and run it syncrhonously (script file will be cached on subsequent requests, file can be minified)

Case 2: will have the script loaded as part of the page (no extra page request), and run when script tag is loaded into dom.

both: will hold up page at that point

Info: http://webdesign.about.com/od/speed/a/script-placement-for-speed.htm